# How to prefix `print` output for each thread in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, logging, printing

How to prefix `print` output for each thread in python ?

```
from threading import Thread

def func1():
    print('Working foo')

def func2():
    print("Working bar")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target = func1).start()
    Thread(target = func2).start()
```

Expected output:

```
[Foo] Working foo
[Bar] Working bar
```

The project is very large so I want to avoid changing the print to logger.

I tried:

```
import sys
import threading

# Custom stream to add prefix to stdout
class PrefixStream:
    def __init__(self, prefix):
        self.prefix = prefix

    def write(self, text):
        sys.stdout.write(self.prefix + " " + text)

# Thread 1 function
def thread1_function():
    # Redirect stdout to custom stream with prefix
    sys.stdout = PrefixStream("[Thread 1]")

    # Thread 1 logic
    print("Thread 1 stdout message")

# Thread 2 function
def thread2_function():
    # Redirect stdout to custom stream with prefix
    sys.stdout = PrefixStream("[Thread 2]")

    # Thread 2 logic
    print("Thread 2 stdout message")

# Create and start the threads
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=thread1_function)
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=thread2_function)

thread1.start()
thread2.start()

# Wait for both threads to complete
thread1.join()
thread2.join()

# Restore stdout to default
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```

But this is not working at all

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can leverage [`threading.get_ident()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.get_ident) ?

```py
import sys
import threading


class CustomPrefixStream:
    def __init__(self):
        self.thread_prefixes = {}

    def add_thread_prefix(self, prefix):
        self.thread_prefixes[threading.get_ident()] = prefix

    def write(self, text):
        if threading.get_ident() in self.thread_prefixes and text != '\n':
            sys.__stdout__.write(f'{self.thread_prefixes[threading.get_ident()]} {text}')
        else:
            sys.__stdout__.write(text)

def thread1_function():
    sys.stdout.add_thread_prefix("[Thread 1]")
    print("Thread 1 stdout message")

def thread2_function():
    sys.stdout.add_thread_prefix("[Thread 2]")
    print("Thread 2 stdout message")

sys.stdout = CustomPrefixStream()

thread1 = threading.Thread(target=thread1_function)
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=thread2_function)

thread1.start()
thread2.start()

thread1.join()
thread2.join()

sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```

Prints:

```
[Thread 1] Thread 1 stdout message
[Thread 2] Thread 2 stdout message
```

Comment: This is a great answer! but there is a problem, when `print("Value is", "123")` it prints the thread tag and every arguments: `[Thread 1] Value is [Thread 1]  [Thread 1] 123` Is it solvable ?

Comment: @TSR It seems you found your answer by yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on Andrej answer, this works without the issue when printing with multiple arguments

```
import sys
import threading


class CustomPrefixStream:
    def __init__(self):
        self.thread_prefixes = {}
        self.buffers = {}

    def add_thread_prefix(self, prefix):
        self.thread_prefixes[threading.get_ident()] = prefix

    def write(self, text):
        thread_id = threading.get_ident()
        self.buffers[thread_id] = self.buffers.get(thread_id, '') + text
        if text == '\n':
            sys.__stdout__.write(f'{self.thread_prefixes[thread_id]} {self.buffers[thread_id]}')
            self.buffers[thread_id] = ''


def thread1_function():
    sys.stdout.add_thread_prefix("[Thread 1]")
    print("Value", "123", True)


def thread2_function():
    sys.stdout.add_thread_prefix("[Thread 2]")
    print("test")
    print("Bar 2 stdout message", "456")


sys.stdout = CustomPrefixStream()

thread1 = threading.Thread(target=thread1_function)
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=thread2_function)

thread1.start()
thread2.start()

thread1.join()
thread2.join()

sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```